# Switch or Case in SQL

Tags: sql, case

I'm writing a store procedure that needs to perform a `SWITCH` of a string variable and doing something different depending on the value, a pseudo-code could be:

```
CASE @my_string
WHEN 'value'
UPDATE table 1
WHEN 'Other_value'
UPDATE table 2
```

I can't find any example of a switch done in this way, is it possible or do I need to use `IF/ELSE` everytime?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `IF` would be the typical way:

```
IF @my_string = 'value'
BEGIN
     UPDATE SomeTable
     WHERE somecondition
END
IF @my_string = 'Other_value'
BEGIN
     UPDATE SomeOtherTable
     WHERE somecondition
END
```